# Httpwebrequest from wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, reporting-services, httpwebrequest

I am new to WCF, I have create one service for httpwebrequest to SSRS report  and render the report in PDF or EXCEL format and save it to specific location on drive.

I am calling this service from web application on button click event. But it is giving an error on GetResponse()

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden
```

Also, I have create same code in console application, It works perfect.

below is my code

```
public class ReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
    {
        public void ReportRequest()
        {
            try
            {
                string URL = "http://localhost/ReportServer2008?/ssrswcf/ssrswcftest";
                string Command = "Render";
                string Format = "PDF";//"EXCEL"

                URL = URL + "&rs:Command=" + Command + "&rs:Format=" + Format + "&sid=5";

                System.Net.HttpWebRequest Req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);

                Req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                Req.Method = "GET";

                string path = @"C:\ssrswcftest\" + Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()) + @".pdf";

                System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = Req.GetResponse();
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                System.IO.Stream stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                while (len > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
                    len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                }
                stream.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

**Below is fiddler details**

**WCF hosted using IIS having error**

**Request Header**

```
GET /ReportServer2008?/ssrswcf/ssrswcftest&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&sid=5 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Negotiate some_long_string
Host: xyz
```

**Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2925
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 15:39:29 GMT
```

**WCF hosted using console application working perfect**

**Request Header**

```
GET /ReportServer2008?/ssrswcf/ssrswcftest&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&sid=5 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Negotiate some_long_string
Host: xyz
```

**Response Header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 25653
Content-Type: application/pdf
Expires: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 16:16:42 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 16:17:43 GMT
Set-Cookie: RSExecutionSession%3a%2fssrswcf%2fssrswcftest=aywu4s45sefnmw45z50bn2vh; path=/
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
FileExtension: pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ssrswcftest.pdf"
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 16:17:42 GMT
```

Comment: I doubt it's the same request that goes out... Use Fiddler to intercept btoh requests and compare them. Maybe a Windows Auth thing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will that now and get back to you.

Comment: I am not sure but fiddler is not showing any request is going through. FYI, I have tried to host same wcf service from console application then it is working correctly, but host wcf from IIS is having issue.

Comment: Fiddler only captures for the current user. You need to set it as a proxy in web.config (or equivalent).

Comment: I have updated question with fiddler details, please let me know if you can get any idea, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just need credential info, when it hosted from IIS. it worked from console because that console application is executing as administrator.

```
public class ReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
    {
        public void ReportRequest()
        {
            try
            {
                string URL = "http://localhost/ReportServer2008?/ssrswcf/ssrswcftest";
                string Command = "Render";
                string Format = "PDF";//"EXCEL"

                URL = URL + "&rs:Command=" + Command + "&rs:Format=" + Format + "&sid=5";

                System.Net.HttpWebRequest Req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);

                Req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password"); 
                Req.Method = "GET";

                string path = @"C:\ssrswcftest\" + Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()) + @".pdf";

                System.Net.WebResponse objResponse = Req.GetResponse();
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                System.IO.Stream stream = objResponse.GetResponseStream();

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                while (len > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
                    len = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                }
                stream.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Authorization: Negotiate` indicates that authentication is in use.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2006/08/02/negotiate-this.aspx) Probably, your WCF service does not have the required credentials. Ask the service owner what authentication is required and configure it.

Comment: I hosted that service using IIS and console application. Calling that service for web application having no issues. Httprequest for wcf service is having issue. Also, I hosted that service using IIS and console application. But only IIS call is having error.

Comment: Isn't it right that the call succeeds when made from a console app and fails when made from anything hosted in IIS?